# setting nested array to variable when index matches

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a large array called $categoryData that is structured like so:

```
array: [
    123=> array:[
        total:[
            red=> 155
            blue=> 200
        ]
    ]
    456=> array:[
        total:[
            red=> 678
            blue=> 443
        ]
    ]
    376=> array:[
        total:[
            red=> 843
            blue=> 456
        ]
    ]
    236=> array:[
        total:[
            red=> 456
            blue=> 890
        ]
    ]
]
```

That's fine, and now I'm looping it to basically set an object to the array for the correct index, in this case 123. So I'm doing this:

```
foreach($categoryData as $data){
    if($data[0] == 123){
        $printData = $data[0];
    }
}

dd($printData);
```

This is giving me `undefined offset: 0`  error and I'm not sure why. I'm getting the correct structure if I dump it within the foreach loop so all I want to do is set the array for the index to `$printData` when it matches, if that makes sense

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your inner array is not numeric, it's associative. Why would you expect the index `0` to exist?

Comment: And you're comparing at the wrong level. Your id is the key of the top level and you're trying to find it on the next level (where the only key is `total`).

Comment: @el_vanja so would I only set it to $data rather than $data[0]

Comment: @el_vanja the index 0 exists in the categoryData array, that's what I'm matching. Then I want everything inside that array to be set to the printData variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you confused with key and values. According to your example, you should compare index, not value:

```
foreach($categoryData as $key=>$data){
    if(123 === $key){
        $printData = $data;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2da5c68ed6038455bf05948c8904e2c268770bce)

---

But, truly say, I don't know why you want to iterate with foreach, when you can get your array by key:

```
$printData = $categoryData[123];
```